# Refresh tableviewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, refresh

I am trying to refresh the table view controller when certain task is performed inside a block.I have checked questions on stackoverflow but they deal with refresh option but i want it to just reload view and go to viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear.This was the suggestions.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

but it doesn't seem to work.Any ideas?

Comment: reload table on main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{[self.tableView reloadData]});`

Comment: Do you want to refresh the table view or table view controller ?

Answer (score 4):

You can not reload `tableview` or update any view inside a block. If you want to update or refresh your table then you will have create a main threaded block and write your code for table refresh on the main thread.

So, try this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    enter code here
});
```

Comment: nice didnt know that..:)